# Eevee Casted Shadows Question

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows, toon-shading

Helo is there a way (In Eevee) to somehow extract and isolate the shadows that are being casted on the plane and connected them do the color map to change the interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - in EEVEE, you can use a *Shader to RGB* node to capture shadow data from a diffuse (or other) shader and then run those values through a *ColorRamp* to change the interpolation :

[image: ShadetoRGB1]

If you already have an image texture (or color) you still want to use, you can multiply the shadow values from the *ColorRamp* over top of it:

[image: SHadetoRGB2]

It works just as well with full PBR sets:

[image: ShadetoRGB3]

If you want simple Toon Shading (as per your tag), make sure to use "constant" interpolation on the ColoRamp, and connect the shadow/color mix directly to the *Material Output* with no shader (BSDF) in between:

[image: Toon]